# Problem with affine root subgroups of $SU_3$ ramified, residue characteristic $p=2$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, p-adic-groups, buildings

Let $L/K$ be ramified quadratic extension of local fields, and let characteristic of the residue field of $K$ be $2$. Let $\mathbb{G}=SU_3$, $G=\mathbb{G}(K)$. Let $\text{val}$ be a valuation on $K$ so that $\text{val}(K^\times) = \mathbb{Z}$ (and $\text{val}(L^\times) = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$).

Following 1.15 and 3.11 in

- J. Tits, *Reductive groups over local fields*, In: Automorphic forms, representations and $L$-functions (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., Oregon State Univ., Corvallis, Ore., 1977), Proc. Sympos. Pure Math. **33** Part 1, (1979) pp. 29–69, doi:[10.1090/pspum/033.1](https://doi.org/10.1090/pspum/033.1),

I have been trying to work out the parahoric subgroups of $G$ attached to the special vertices $\nu_0$ and $\nu_1$ in the building of $G$.

Firstly, I'll start with a description of the root subgroups of $G$. I'm using a slightly different notation from Tits'. Let $$u_+(c,d) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -\bar{c} & d \\ 0 & 1 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$
with $\bar{c}c+d+\bar{d}=0$.
Similarly, $$u_-(c,d) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ c & 1 & 0 \\ d & -\bar{c} & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$
with $\bar{c}c+d+\bar{d}=0$.

We have the root subgroups $U_{\pm a}(K) = \{ u_\pm(c,d) \text{ : } c,d \in L \}$ and $U_{\pm 2a} = \{ u_\pm(0,d) \text{ : } d \in L\}$.

Tits later defines $\delta = sup\{\text{val}(d) \text{ : } d \in L, \,\ \bar{d}+d+1=0\}$. $\delta=0$ in the unramified case and in the ramified, residue characteristic $p\neq 2$ case. However, when $L/K$ is ramified with residue characteristic $2$, $\delta$ is strictly negative.

From here, Tits finds the set of affine roots of $G$ as $$\Big\{\pm a + \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z} +\frac{\delta}{2}\Big\} \cup \Big\{\pm 2a +\mathbb{Z}+ \frac{1}{2} + \delta \Big\}.$$

Affine root subgroups are given by $$U_{\pm a + \gamma/2} = \{ u_\pm(c,d) \text{ : } \text{val}(d) \geq \gamma\},$$
$$U_{\pm 2a+ \gamma} = \{ u_\pm(0,d) \text{ : } \text{val}(d) \geq \gamma\}.$$

The special points $\nu_0$ and $\nu_1$ i the standard apartment are defined by $$a(\nu_1)=\frac{\delta}{2}, \,\ a(\nu_0) = \frac{\delta}{2} + \frac{1}{4}.$$

From here, one can find that $$G_{\nu_1} = \langle T_0, U_{a-\frac{\delta}{2}}, U_{-a+\frac{\delta}{2}}, U_{2a+\frac{1}{2}-\delta}, U_{-2a+\frac{1}{2}+\delta} \rangle,$$
$$G_{\nu_0} = \langle T_0, U_{a-\frac{\delta}{2}}, U_{-a+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\delta}{2}}, U_{2a-\frac{1}{2}-\delta}, U_{-2a+\frac{1}{2}+\delta} \rangle.$$

In 3.11, Tits takes a $\lambda \in L$ with $\text{val}(\lambda) = \delta$, satisfying $\lambda+\bar{\lambda}+1=0$ in a way such that $\lambda \varpi_L + \overline{(\lambda \varpi_L)}=0$ for some uniformizer $\varpi_L$ of the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_L$ of $L$.

In 3.11, Tits defines the lattices $$\Lambda_{\nu_1} = \mathcal{O}_L \oplus \mathcal{O}_L \oplus \lambda\mathcal{O}_L,$$
$$\Lambda_{\nu_0} = \varpi_L^{-1}\mathcal{O}_L \oplus \mathcal{O}_L \oplus \lambda\mathcal{O}_L.$$ Let $P_{\nu_1}$ and $P_{\nu_0}$ be their respective stabilizers.
Tits then states that $G_{\nu_i} = P_{\nu_i} \cap G_{\nu_i}$ for $i=0,1$.

Here's where my problem comes in.

Consider $G_{\nu_1} = \langle T_0, U_{a-\frac{\delta}{2}}, U_{-a+\frac{\delta}{2}}, U_{2a+\frac{1}{2}-\delta}, U_{-2a+\frac{1}{2}+\delta} \rangle.$ The stabilizer of the lattice $\Lambda_{\nu_1}$ in $GL_3(L)$ has the form
$$\begin{pmatrix} \mathcal{O}_L & \mathcal{O}_L & \mathfrak{p}_L^{-2\delta} \\ \mathcal{O}_L & \mathcal{O}_L & \mathfrak{p}_L^{-2\delta} \\ \mathfrak{p}_L^{2\delta} & \mathfrak{p}_L^{2\delta} & \mathcal{O}_L \end{pmatrix}.$$
Since $\text{val}(\delta) < 0$, intersecting this stabilizer with $G$ would give us a matrix roughly looking like
$$\begin{pmatrix} \mathcal{O}_L & \mathfrak{p}_L^{-2\delta} & \mathfrak{p}_L^{-2\delta} \\ \mathcal{O}_L & \mathcal{O}_L & \mathfrak{p}_L^{-2\delta} \\ \mathfrak{p}_L^{2\delta} & \mathcal{O}_L & \mathcal{O}_L \end{pmatrix},$$

Presumeably, this would tell us that $$U_{a-\frac{\delta}{2}} = \{ u_+(c,d) \text{ : } c,d \in L, \,\ \text{val}(d) \geq -\delta \textbf{ and } \text{val}(c) \geq -\delta \},$$
$$U_{-a+\frac{\delta}{2}} = \{u_{-}(c,d) \text{ : } c,d \in L, \,\ \text{val}(d) \geq \delta \textbf{ and } \text{val}(c) \geq 0 \}.$$
Normally, one would expect that if $\text{val}(d) = \gamma$, then $\text{val}(d) = \frac{\gamma}{2}$ or $\frac{\gamma}{2}+\frac{1}{4}$, as whether $\gamma \in \mathbb{Z}$ or just $\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$.

I cannot work out algebraically why we have these improved bounds on the valuation of $c$ for these affine root subgroups. I assume it involves some manipulation with $\lambda$, but I am not making any progress.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know anything about this situation, but the first place I'd look would be Section 2 of Prasad and Raghunathan's _Topological central extensions of semi-simple groups over local fields_ (Ann. Math. **119**).  While they might go into more detail than you want, and they're concerned with absolutely simple groups in general, they don't seem to be making any tameness assumptions.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a look.